# Installing python 3.5 on Opensuse leap

Tags: linux, python-3.x, python-3.5, opensuse

Current version: Python 3.4.5
Distribution: Opensuse Leap 42.2
I want to replace it with 3.5.*, I tried doing:

```
sudo zypper ar -f http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/languages:/python3/openSUSE_Leap_42.2/devel:languages:python3.repo
sudo zypper ref
sudo zypper dup
```

but still when doing dup it won't upgrade from 3.4 to 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in case someone comes across this in the future, changing the default python(3) in the OS is a bad idea, some OS applications might be reliant on this exact version to run correctly, if you find yourself in a situation similar to this, better use virtualenv, pyenv(https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) or conda(https://conda.io/docs/intro.html)